# Could we inspect the packet stats while using tc(traffic control)?

Tags: linux, ifconfig, traffic-simulation

I tried to use [tc](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) to simulate packets corruption and view the network interface statistics via ifconfig or cat /proc/net/dev.

The packets corruption worked as expected, However I was wondering if we could inspect the result via ifconfig?

Step 1. Create packet corruption

```
~$ tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem corrupt 10%
```

Step 2. Send packets

```
~$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

Step 3. Inspect ping result, icmp_seq 85,89 and 90 is missing as expected.

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=84 ttl=109 time=7.41 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=86 ttl=109 time=7.45 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=87 ttl=109 time=7.45 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=89 ttl=109 time=7.51 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=91 ttl=109 time=7.43 ms
```

Step 4. Inspect network interface

```
~$ ifconfig

eth0: flags=4163 mtu 9001
inet 10.100.100.41 netmask 255.255.255.224 broadcast 10.100.100.63
inet6 fe80::af:d5ff:fe32:eb24 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20
ether 02:af:d5:33:eb:24 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 522086 bytes 693054828 (693.0 MB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 238600 bytes 23556732 (23.5 MB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I was wondering why **ifconfig** shows there is no packet errors, dropped?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I reformatted my post due to the down vote. Feedback is welcome.

Comment: Suggestions are welcomed